# Using component to render a list item in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, components

Can I use a component as a list item which is declared in another component?
For example, I want to have this in my html file of the calling component:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <my-new-component></my-new-component>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

And in my new component I want to use a template which declares the li itself:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .component('myNewComponent', {
        template: '<li ng-click="$ctrl.onItemClick()">Item3</li>',
        controller: MyController
    });
```

Currently it's not working, and I guess I should compile the template somehow, but I havn't figured out how.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you mean to say, you wanted to be your component to render `li` element, but AFAIK `component` will not replace its template, it will add template inside component element(`replace: true` deprecated in `component`), I think that is what you are asking..

Comment: Thanks for the correction.
Actually, I did try 'replace: true' but still no luck

Comment: because `replace: true` has been deprecated..